# Telerik MVC Grid Post Data Subject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I am a Web Developer and Nowadays Using ASP.Net. I am Developing an Enterprise Level Application in Which I Need to Use a Grid to Perform CRUD Operations on Data.
I am Trying to use Telerik Grid for MVC3. It is Nice But I am Facing Some Problems When I Send Data to Server Throw Ajax After Modification.
I did not Find any Way to do That. Ajax Call Goes to The Server But No Data is Passed.
The Question is "How to Post Data From Telerik Grid to The Controller After Modifying or Inserting New Records Throw Ajax".
Please Specify Both BachEditing and Single Row Editing. I have Tried Both But I Could not Send Data To The Controller.
That Will Help me a lot.

Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

Did you saw example http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editingajax

I think you forgot for datakey  `.DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.CustomerID))`
Post your code.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Sanja Melnichuk. I Think There is Miss Understanding I have already Tried That Above Example But I Want to Send Modified Data not Just Call. Ajax Call Has Gone But Data is Not.